# Update a function to include tail recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I have the following function that determines the maximum element of a given list.

```
maxList :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maxList l =
    let iMaxList :: Ord a => [a] -> a
        iMaxList [] = error( "Empty list" )
        iMaxList [x] = x
        iMaxList ( x:xs )
            | x > t = x
            | otherwise = t
            where t = iMaxList xs
    in iMaxList l
```

Yet, it doesn't use tail recursion and I'd like it to do so.
I tried to use an accumulator to comply with the tail recursion principle in Haskell.

```
maxList :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maxList ( x:xs ) = loop( xs, x )
                  where loop( x:xs, m )
                            | ( null xs ) = m
                            | ( x >= m ) = loop( xs, x )
                            | otherwise = loop( xs, m )
```

Yet, it logically fails because of this guard `(null xs) = m`. Indeed, if we take the list `[1,2,3,4]`, `4`will never be evaluated.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Consider using pattern matching more than guards: `loop ([],m) = m; loop (x:xs,m) = ...`.  At any rate, your `null xs` case is where you ignore the last `x` value.

Comment: Incidentally, in your original `maxList`, the auxiliary definition of `iMaxList` serves no purpose: since `maxList l = iMaxList l` (and `iMaxList` doesn't ever refer to the original `l`), the two functions are identical. You might as well just add the pattern matches to `maxList` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listMax :: Ord a => [a] -> a
listMax [] = error "Tried to find maximum of an empty list."
listMax (x:xs) = listMax' xs x where
  listMax' :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> a
  listMax' [] y = y
  listMax' (x:xs) y | x > y     = listMax' xs x
                    | otherwise = listMax' xs y
```

In this case, y is the accumulating parameter that holds the maximum value found so far.  Brief proof of correctness: the algorithm terminates because each tail-recursive call removes one element from the input list until it is empty.  The final value of `y` it returns is the maximum because, for every other element `x` in the input, either `y > x` or `y > z > x` for some `z` after `x` and before `y`.  (This assumes that `>` is transitive.)

You could also write the helper function this way:

```
listMax' :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> a
listMax' [] y = y
listMax' (x:xs) y = listMax' xs (max x y)
```

And this implementation does the same thing:

```
listMax2 :: Ord a => [a] -> a
listMax2 [] = error "Tried to find maximum of an empty list."
listMax2 list = foldl1 max list
```

The `foldl1` function is a tail-recursive lazy evaluation from front to back, but the strict `foldl1'` version or `foldr1` might be more efficient in this case.  The first version is closer to strict evaluation than lazy.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what your are searching for:

```
maxList' :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maxList'     []   = error "Empty List"
maxList'    [x]   = x
maxList' (x:y:xs) = maxList' (max x y:xs)
```

The function uses the same list that is processing to store the biggest number found so far. It seems to comply with the tail recursion definition, ie: the recursive call is the very last thing in the computation of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it.

I wrote the following in a file:

```
module MaxList (maxList) where

import Data.List

maxList :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maxList = foldl1' max
```

Then I compiled it with `-O2 -ddump-simpl`, to have a look at the optimised Core. After a bit of cleaning up - GHC generates a lot of variables with names that are difficult to read - the generated code looks like this:

```
maxList [] = error "empty list"
maxList (x:xs) = go xs x
    where go ys y =
              case ys of
                   [] -> y;
                   (z:zs) -> case y of  -- force y to WHNF before continuing
                                  _ -> go zs (max y z)
```

`go` is tail recursive. In fact it's the same as the code in [@Davislor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43990117/7951906)! I used `foldl1'` - a high-level control structure - and GHC generated exactly the code that you would've written by hand if you wanted to write a tail recursive loop.

Haskell's philosophy is that you should use high-level tools like folds, unfolds, monads, classes, etc, and rely on the compiler to generate good code. There certainly is an art to writing code which GHC will do a good job of optimising - you don't always get it for free - but you usually shouldn't need to unroll high-level structures into low-level loops because GHC is good at that.